# load iAd again on parent UIViewController after coming back form child view?

Tags: ios

I have 2 views(parent and child). I have an iAd displaying on the parent and don't want the ad on the child. So before calling the child, I am removing the iAd. Now, When I am coming back to the parent from the child view, I want the iAd to pop back up. I tried doing this by calling the viewDidLoad/viewWillLoad methods, but they don't seem to be called. I have seen similar questions, but they don't seem to be working.

I am calling the removeFromSuperview before calling the actual child view

```
-(IBAction) switchView:(id)sender{
about *svc = [[about alloc] initWithNibName:@"about" bundle:nil];
[adView removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:svc.view];
}
```

and am trying to revive the iAd by using 
    [self.view addSubview:adView];

Can Someone please tell me what method is called when the parent view is loaded again so that I can load the iAd form there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just doing `[adView setHidden: YES]` when switching to the child view and `[adView setHidden: NO]` when going back to the parent?

One more suggestion:  Objective C convention is to capitalize classes.  So instead of a class named "about", it should be named "About".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but that was the question, the viewDidLoad/viewWillLoad doesn't seem to be called when the child view gets removed. So, where do I put [adView setHidden: NO]? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Also, thanks for the suggestion about 'About'. Ill keep that in mind!

Comment: viewDidLoad & viewWillLoad only gets called when the **view controller** (not the view) gets loaded for the first (and hopefully) only time when it's needed by your app.  Your view controller appears to be managing a number of different views (a parent, a child and an iAd view).  Put `[adView setHidden: YES]` into your `switchView:` action.

Comment: Ya, I already put the [adView setHidden: YES] in my switchview and it works fine. The problem I am having is when the control returns to the parent view. I am not able to get it visible! Where do I put the  [adView setHidden: NO], which method?

Comment: put the `[adView setHidden: NO]` line right underneath the place where you go from the child view back to the parent view (presumably via a `removeFromSuperview` call).

Comment: but adview is declared in the parent and cannot be used in the child !

Comment: you can either send a message (`NSNotification`) to the parent that it's time to display an ad again, or you can put a reference to adView in your child view controller (to set it to visible again when the child view disappears).  There's a few ways to solve this.